# Update sub fields from repeater with different values in WordPress ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to update 4 different sub fields from a repeater with 4 different values that i get from a json.

The thing is i'm able to update all the sub fields with a single value(the same for all 4 sub fields), but not with different values.

What I have is:  (Sorry i dont know how to add php to the snippet)

Code Link:
[Link](https://gyazo.com/cd007fe34aed23a2739c4f564047c1f6)

I've created also an array of the different urls..

$counter = 0; if(have_rows('branch','option')): while(have_rows('branch','option')): the_row();

```
      $ch = curl_init();
      
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kuala_Lumpur.json');
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      $obj = json_decode($result);
      $value = $obj->utc_offset; 
      
      update_sub_field('timezone', $value); ?>


        <div class="clock-wrapper" data-timezone="<?php the_sub_field('timezone'); ?>">
```

I have 4 different values I got from the URL:

```
worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London.json
worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Australia/Perth.json
worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Madrid.json
```

How could I give to each sub field one of the values?

Comment: _“(Sorry i dont know how to add php to the snippet)”_ - you add the code in your question, select all of it, and then you press the `{}` button to get it displayed properly formatted.

Comment: @04FS done, hope its better now

Comment: So it looks like this isn’t actually about how to update a specific sub field, but your actual problem is that you need to make your cURL request to different endpoints to begin with. Do you have those time zone names stored inside your repeater as well somehow? If not, then I guess you can only put them into an array, and then use a loop counter to access them one after the other.

Comment: @04FS Yup i've put them on an array, should now I loop somehow to display a different url por every div?

Comment: No, just use your loop counter to access the elements from that array one by one.

Comment: @04FS Yeah thats it! I don't know why i didnt think about an array... lol Thanks dude